# Transform a symmetric matrix to a vector and multiplicate

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

Assume that we have a matrix symmetric matrix $A = \mathbb{R}^{nxn}$. It es enough to look only at the lower triangle. What I want to do is to transform the matrix into a vector:

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \dots\\
2 & 3 & \dots\\
4 &5&6&\dots\\ 
7&8&9&10&\dots\\\dots
\end{pmatrix}
$\rightarrow$
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
2\\
3\\
4\\
\dots
\end{pmatrix}

Thus i have a bijection $(i,j) \rightarrow k$, where $i,j$ are the matrix indicies and $k$ is the vector index.

I already found the expression $$k = \frac{i(i-1)}{2} + j$$

but I don't know how to get the inverse transformation. Do you have any ideas how to do this?

The deaper reason behind this is that I want to save calculation time in my simulation. As this procedure requires only to look at half of the matrix entries it should significantly decrease the run time of a matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll refer to your equation as $\left(1\right)$.

Since $j \geq 1$, we want $i$ to be the largest integer no greater than the solution for $i$ in equation $\left(1\right)$ with $j$ set to $1$.

Putting $x$ instead of $i$ (because initially we want a real solution):

\begin{eqnarray*}
x^2 - x + 2 - 2k &=& 0 \\
x &=& \dfrac{1 \pm \sqrt{1 + 8k - 8}}{2} \\
&=& \dfrac{1 + \sqrt{8k - 7}}{2}\qquad\left(\mbox{since we need $x>0$}\right)
\end{eqnarray*}

So $i = \lfloor{x}\rfloor = \lfloor{\dfrac{1 + \sqrt{8k - 7}}{2}}\rfloor$

Once you have $i$, you substitute $k$ and $i$ into equation $\left(1\right)$ to get $j$.

Example: $k = 10$:
\begin{eqnarray*}
i &=& \lfloor{\dfrac{1 + \sqrt{80 - 7}}{2}}\rfloor \\
 &=& 4.
\end{eqnarray*}

Then $j = 10 - \dfrac{4 \times 3}{2} = 4$